# Should duplicate questions be marked as "answered" after being marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I try to make sure all my questions are checked off as "answered" when the answer is found. Recently, I posted this question: [What's the difference between using `.catch(function(error)` and `function(errResponse)` when handing errors from AngularJS promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152989/whats-the-difference-between-using-catchfunctionerror-and-functionerrre) and turns out it was a duplicate, and was already answered here: [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises)

My post is now marked as a duplicate and a great answer can be found in the duplicate post. However, when I go through my profile and look at the questions I asked, the box with the upvote / downvote count is white, not green (from my understanding, this means the question is not answered).

There are three other answers to my question (which are good answers, but the best one is in the duplicate post). With that said, I want to mark this question as answered because, well, it is (just answered in a different post). Do I just pick one of the three answers in my post, or do I leave it unanswered?

Comment: Since acceptance checkmark has no other value than "helped OP" I don't see much value in adding it to people closed duplicates.